# Multiple button press

Tags: c#, button

I have 4 labels with visibility set to false and a button. Every time I click on the button I want it to show me a different label. Could someone please tell me the code for this?

Comment: Randomly? Or in some order? When showing up should it make the other invisible?

Comment: i tried with switch statement, but i dont know how to use it right. I'm really new at this

Comment: @ nawfal: i would prefer in order, and yes make the other invisible again

Answer (score 6):

A `Queue` is tailor made for this task.

```
private Queue<Label> queue = new Queue<Label>();
//add labels to queue in constructor

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    queue.Peek().Visible = false; //hide label at the start of the queue
    queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue()); //move the first item to the end
    queue.Peek().Visible = true; //show the label at the start of the queue
}
```